# Splitting CSR Matrix Horizontally, by the number of Nonzero values

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following code : given that (`numPartitions` = 4)

```py
from scipy import sparse

def horizontalSplit(matrix, numPartitions):
    csr = sparse.csr_matrix(loadGraph(matrix))
    submatrices = []
    # align partition size (rowcount) to 64 - good for bursts and
    # updating the input vector bits independently
    stepSize = int(alignedIncrement(csr.shape[0] / numPartitions,0,64))
    print ('===Data=====')
    print(csr.shape[0]," - ",numPartitions, " - ",stepSize)
    print("=======================\n")
    # create submatrices, last one includes the remainder
    currentRow = int(0)
    for i in range(0, numPartitions):
        if i != numPartitions - 1:
            submatrices += [csr[currentRow:currentRow + stepSize]]  # essentially this is initally csr[0:0+stepsize] = csr[0:stepsize]  
        else:
            submatrices += [csr[currentRow:]]
        currentRow += stepSize
    return submatrices

# Create an 8x8 adjacency matrix with the modified element
adjacency_matrix = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
]
csr_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix(adjacency_matrix)
horizontalSplit(csr_matrix,4)
```

This behaves such a way that if the adjacency matrix is like the following :

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
2 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
3 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
5 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
6 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
7 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

It splits it (2x8) and the submatrices become like the following :

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
------------------
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
------------------
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
------------------
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Looking at Column 0, it would have been more intelligently divided by getting each number of non zero to each submatrix.

I have coded the following to split in this way but it doesn't split correctly which shows me a single row submatrices :

```py
def horizontalSplit(matrix, numPartitions):
    csr = sparse.csr_matrix(matrix)
    submatrices = []

    # Calculate the number of non-zeros in each row
    row_nonzeros = csr.getnnz(axis=1)

    # Calculate the target number of non-zeros for each partition
    target_nonzeros = sum(row_nonzeros) // numPartitions

    currentRow = 0
    currentNonZeros = 0

    for i in range(numPartitions):
        # Allocate rows to the current partition until the target number of non-zeros is reached
        while currentRow < csr.shape[0] and currentNonZeros < target_nonzeros:
            row = csr[currentRow]
            submatrices.append(row)
            currentNonZeros += row_nonzeros[currentRow]
            currentRow += 1

        # Reset the count for the next partition
        currentNonZeros = 0

    return submatrices
```

Is submatrices.append wrong way of doing this by only incrementing currentRow by just 1 ?

I have tried splitting by the number of nonzeros but it didn't work

Comment: `row` is a (1,8) csr matrix.  So `submatrices` will a list of all such matrices.

Comment: if you calculated the nnz for row before hand, can't you use that to select the step sizes to use when splitting ranges (as done in the first case)?  No point to splitting one row at a time (much less trying to reassemble those 1 row matrices)

Comment: Your `nnz` by row is `array([4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2])`.  What's the 'inteligent' way of splitting those rows?  [6,5,5,5] is the same 2 row split you originally got.

Comment: This is not reproducible because we do not have `loadGraph`.