# Partitioning Sparse Matrix into Smaller Chunks by the number of nonzero values

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I have the following code :

```py
import io, sys, numpy, scipy, struct, os
import numpy as np
from scipy import io
from scipy import sparse
from numpy import inf
import random as rnd
import sys
from scipy import sparse

def myhorsplit(matrix,numPartitions):
    csr = sparse.csr_matrix(matrix)
    input_array = csr.getnnz(0)
    print(input_array)
        # Step 1: Calculate the total
    total = sum(input_array)

    # Step 3: Set number of compute units to 4
    num_compute_units = 4
 
    partitions = [[] for _ in range(num_compute_units)]
    current_sums = [0] * num_compute_units
    for element in input_array:
        # Find the partition with the smallest current sum
        min_partition = min(range(num_compute_units), key=lambda i: current_sums[i])

        # Add the element to the selected partition
        partitions[min_partition].append(element)
        current_sums[min_partition] += element

    for i, partition in enumerate(partitions):
        print(f"Partition {i}: {partition}")
    print("Rows Result:")
    print(csr.tolil().rows[0])
    print("Get Column Result:")
    print(csr.tolil().getcol(1))
    
    return partition

# Create an 8x8 adjacency matrix with the modified element
adjacency_matrix = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
]
csr_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix(adjacency_matrix)
# horizontalSplit(csr_matrix,4)
myhorsplit(csr_matrix,4)
```

Which prints out :

```
[4 2 5 2 3 2 1 2]
Partition 0: [4, 1]
Partition 1: [2, 3]
Partition 2: [5]
Partition 3: [2, 2, 2]
Rows Result:
[0, 1, 2, 3]
Get Column Result:
  (0, 0)        1
  (2, 0)        1
```

I couldn't find a way that partition this sparse matrix into smaller chunks such that the first 3 chunks ( assuming I want 4 chunks ) to have total nonzero values/4 and the last chunk to have the rest of the nonzeros ?

Comment: previous version of this problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490292/splitting-csr-matrix-horizontally-by-the-number-of-nonzero-values

Comment: It might be easier to ask, and answer, if you worked with `numpy` and dense arrays.  I think specifying sparse limits the attention this gets.  The splitting logic should work just as well with numpy arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj the issue is the dataset is quite large so can't work with dense arrays. I would like to split it with sparse method

Comment: But slicing by rows or by columns is the same whether you use ndarray or csr. As best I can tell the problem isn't how to slice, but where.  And I'm the only one who's paying much attention to the question (or your previous)

Comment: Sparse is an interesting challenge, but I can take a stab at it.

Comment: Since your partitions are not contiguous sub-matrices within the original matrix, I don't particularly consider this to be partitioning; it's assignment. You've mentioned "compute units", so this is performance-sensitive. Why not select contiguous sub-matrices and do proper partitioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a parallelization partitioning problem, you're going through a lot of trouble that seems unnecessary. This will perform better in terms of setup runtime if you keep the partitions contiguous. ([Use arrays, not matrices!](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html))

```py
def myhorsplit(
    matrix: sparse.sparray, n_compute_units: int = 4,
) -> list[sparse.sparray]:
    nnz = matrix.getnnz(axis=1).cumsum()
    total = nnz[-1]
    ideal_breaks = np.arange(0, total, total/n_compute_units)
    break_idx = [*nnz.searchsorted(ideal_breaks), None]
    return [
        matrix[i: j, :]
        for i, j in zip(break_idx[:-1], break_idx[1:])
    ]
```

The output is not very accurate for small arrays:

```
Partition 0: 4 ones, shape (1, 8)
[[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]]
Partition 1: 5 ones, shape (2, 8)
[[1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]]
Partition 2: 6 ones, shape (3, 8)
[[1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
Partition 3: 6 ones, shape (2, 8)
[[0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]]
```

but your actual array is huge, and as the array size grows, accuracy improves; with a large, randomly-generated array:

```py
def main() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    # Create an 8x8 adjacency matrix with the modified element
    adjacency_matrix = [
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
        (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
        (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    ]
    # csr_matrix = sparse.csr_array(adjacency_matrix)
    csr_matrix = sparse.csr_array(
        rand.integers(low=0, high=2, size=(10_000, 50), dtype=np.uint8)
    )

    partitions = myhorsplit(csr_matrix)

    for i, partition in enumerate(partitions):
        print(f"Partition {i}: {partition.nnz} ones, shape {partition.shape}")
        # print(partition.toarray())
```

```
Partition 0: 62316 ones, shape (2498, 50)
Partition 1: 62339 ones, shape (2506, 50)
Partition 2: 62332 ones, shape (2494, 50)
Partition 3: 62348 ones, shape (2502, 50)
```

If you want to do better in terms of partitioning accuracy and you allow for arbitrary, non-contiguous assignment, this is a backpack problem which would take its own time to run and would use e.g. `scipy.optimize.milp`.

Comment: It gives an attribute error for sparse.sparray and recommends changing it to sparse.bsr_array. I did google it and installed newer version of scipy and downgraded networx package but it didn't work. I was wondering if there is any difference between both ?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not enough to go on. But yes, you should be running a contemporary version of scipy.

Comment: I got it fixed and works. Thank you very much but I have one more quick question. The order of the partitions are changed in Partition 2 since it is sorting them via searchsort function. Is there a way to not sort these values and just get their values in order. Like : 
Partition2 : [[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1],[1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0] ,[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]]

Comment: The "sorted" in `searchsorted` refers to the fact that the cumulative sum of the non-zero counts is guaranteed monotonic. There is no other sorting being performed.

Comment: it shouldn't reorder the partition 2 which results in wrong values since this is a graph representation. Is it related with how return is set up ?

Comment: There is no re-ordering being done. Re-examine the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255981/discussion-between-solarlate-and-reinderien).